# set selected item of drop downlist equal to a text box

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

How can I make my drop down list shows the value in my text box? The value is always one the items of drop down list, but how can I set the selected item of drop down list equals to the value of my textbox, after click?

```
 $('<input  name="Product Name" data-type="string" \>')
     .appendTo(container)
     .kendoDropDownList({
         dataSource: mydata,
         dataTextField: "Text",
  });
```

Comment: you want to set the text box value, from the value of the drop-down selection?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee other way round ,I want to set the value of dropdownlist(selected value) from txt box

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand what you're trying to accomplish,  you can do it like this

```
var selectList = document.getElementById('selectList');
selectList.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var selectedVal = selectList.value;
    var inputText = document.getElementById('textInput');
  inputText.value = selectedVal;
});
```

See it in action -> **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohit0094arora/f3fLohk5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (it's just an example of the way how to set the value)

```
$("#Instrument").kendoDropDownList({
  dataTextField: "symbol",
  dataValueField: "symbol",
  dataSource: data,
  index: 0
});

var dropdownlist = $("#YourId").data("kendoDropDownList");    
dropdownlist.select(function (dataItem) {
    return dataItem.symbol === "Your value from input or whatever";
});
```

PS: in "dataItem.symbol" symbol is your dataTextField: "symbol"